How to resolve java.sql.SQLException: Fail to construct descriptor (i.e. weblogic-ra.xml)
Exception occurred when binding was invoked.
Exception occurred during invocation of JCA binding: "JCA Binding execute of Reference operation 'LoadOrder' failed due to: Parse struct conversion error.
An error occurred while parsing XML representing a Java struct.
Unable to convert the XSD element I_POS_TRANS whose user defined type is SOA_ECOMM.T_POS_TRN_REC to a Java struct. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Fail to construct descriptor: Unable to resolve type "SOA_ECOMM.T_POS_TRN_REC"
Check to ensure that the XML data describing the user defined type matches the definition of the struct in the XSD.  This exception is considered not retriable, likely due to a modelling mistake.  To classify it as retriable instead add property nonRetriableErrorCodes with value "-17060" to your deployment descriptor (i.e. weblogic-ra.xml).  To auto retry a retriable fault set these composite.xml properties for this invoke: jca.retry.interval, jca.retry.count, and jca.retry.backoff.  All properties are integers.
".
The invoked JCA adapter raised a resource exception.
Please examine the above error message carefully to determine a resolution.

As per MOS Doc ID 2324018.1 this is a bug which needs to Apply patch 26975077.
